# Linear Algebra Basics: Computing Eigenvector with Repeated Roots

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My text only provides a cursory understanding of following problem & I'm looking for a better framework to compute and apply the following eigenvector. I apologize for granular simplicity and step-by-step approach.

$$
\text { Solve } \mathbf{X}^{\prime}=\left(\begin{array}{lll}2 & 1 & 6 \\ 0 & 2 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{array}\right) \mathbf{X}
$$

Characteristic equation $(\lambda-2)^{3}=0$ gives $ \lambda_1 = 2 $. Solving the system $(\mathbf{A}-2 \mathbf{I}) \mathbf{V}=\mathbf{0}$:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{lll}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}v_{1} \\ v_{2} \\ v_{3}\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right)
$$
So we have $\boldsymbol{v}=\left(\begin{array}{l}v_{1} \\ v_{2} \\ v_{3}\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}v_{1} \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right)$. Letting $ v_1 = 1 $, we get $\boldsymbol{v}=\left(\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right)$ as the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 2. Part of my confusion, as seen below, comes from this idea of "letting" variables take on specific scalars.

Next I solve the systems $(\mathbf{A}-2 \mathbf{I}) \mathbf{P}=\mathbf{V}$ and $(\mathbf{A}-2 \mathbf{I}) \mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{P}$, and the text provides:
$$
\mathbf{P}=\left(\begin{array}{l}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right) \quad \text { and } \quad \mathbf{Q}=\left(\begin{array}{r}0 \\ -\frac{6}{5} \\ \frac{1}{5}\end{array}\right)
$$

Solving for P via $(\mathbf{A}-2 \mathbf{I}) \mathbf{P}=\mathbf{V}$ and augmenting the eigenvector V:
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$
I get $ p_2 = 1, p_3 = 0$ so $P=\left(\begin{array}{l}p_1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right)$.

**Q**: I'm confused on how we're computing P here. Similar to the eigenvector (letting $ v_1 = 1$) here it seems we're taking $ p_1 = 0$. Why? Any help is much appreciated. The system btw is a homogeneous differential equation.

Comment: It looks good to me. I checked your $P$ and $V$ and it's correct

Comment: I edit the question incase of ambiguity, but I'm confused on the calculation of P. Similar to the eigenvector (letting $ v_1 = 1$), but in this case $ p_1 = 0$ and I don't understand that conceptually.

Comment: You can choose any vector of the form $(p_1,1,0)$ as eigenvector so the textbook chooses the most simple $(0,1,0)$

Comment: I see. For instance (1, 1, 0) would also be correct for the P vector?

Comment: Yes of course it's correct too.